# How to clone an element on click in React.js

Tags: reactjs, onclick, click, clone

I'm a beginner to react.js, and i'm using typescript for that.

I want to create an element that will duplicate itself on click, how would I do that?
This is the current code:

```
import React from "react";

interface Props {
  emoji: string;
  text: string;
}

const Item = ({ emoji, text }: Props) => {
  const HandleClick = () => {};

  return (
    <>
      <div className="item" onClick={HandleClick}>
        <span className="emoji">{emoji}</span>
        <span className="text">{text}</span>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Item;
```

Tried to search on the internet, no success yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code. When you click on the Item, then it will clone itself.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

interface Props {
  emoji: string;
  text: string;
}

const Item = ({ emoji, text }: Props) => {

// Stores the number of clicks and clones
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setCount(count + 1); // Track the number of clicks and clones
  };

  return (
    <>
      {new Array(count + 1).fill(null).map((_, index) => (
        <div key={index} className="item" onClick={handleClick}>
          <span className="emoji">{emoji}</span>
          <span className="text">{text}</span>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default Item;
```